# WPF WebBrowser custom right click menu stopped working after migrating the app to .NET Core 3.1

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, contextmenu, .net-core-3.1

I've got a WPF application that uses the `WebBrowser` control as an HTML viewer. I didn't want it to have the default right click context menu so I've found this piece of code to display my custom one instead.

```cs
private void TheBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    documentEvents = TheBrowser.Document as HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event;
    if (documentEvents != null)
    {
        documentEvents.oncontextmenu += webBrowserChat_ContextMenuOpening;
    }
}

private bool webBrowserChat_ContextMenuOpening(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
{
    return false;
}
```

That has worked just fine until I've migrated the app from .NET Framework 4.7 to .NET Core 3.1.

Now it throws this exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Inner exception
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.UCOMIConnectionPointContainer' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

None the ways to disable the context menu I found works in .NET Core WPF. I don't really need to have my custom menu, just disabling it altogether would do.

If there's a "new" way to do it in .NET Core 3.1 please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you cast `pEvtObj` to a `ContextMenu`? Why just doesn't return `false` from `webBrowserChat_ContextMenuOpening`? This works in .NET Core.

Comment: @mm8 I've removed that bit and I'm only returning `false` now, still doesn't work. (I've been casting the `pEvtObj` to a `ContextMenu` so I could display my own context menu). Do you have a working example on GitHub or something?

Comment: "...casting the pEvtObj to a ContextMenu so I could display my own context menu" makes no sense. Please provide a reproducible example of your issue.

Comment: @mm8 forget about the custom context menu part. I just want to disable the default WebBrowser context menu. My code it exactly like I've put it here, however, it doesn't work. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: No, I haven't, because it works for me.

Comment: I'm using the Unofficial.Microsoft.mshtml nuget package, are you using that as well?

Comment: No, why would I and why haven't you mentioned this in your question?

Comment: I didn't think it was important. My idea was that the Unofficial.Microsoft.mshtml is just the nugget version for the regular mshtml library. What are you using then?

Comment: Project->Add Reference->COM->Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: It works! I've removed the nuget and added the Microsoft HTML Object Library as a reference. It doesn't throw exceptions anymore, however, the context menu shows up once I select some text in the browser. How do you prevent that from happening?